# What should the human-factors tag be used for or should it be used at all?

Tags: discussion, tags

**Update:**

I burned the tag. It didn't seemed to be used much and of the few times it was used about half were done incorrectly as for my guess of what it was meant to be used for.

As no one seemed to be able to say what it should be used for, it was easier to just burn it.

**End Update:**

I have been going through the tags and adding usage guidance statements to those lacking when I came across the [human-factors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-factors) tag and I don't know what the usage case would be.

Sometimes I can find a better tag to switch a bad one out with, but this one is stumping me and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_factors_and_ergonomics) isn't much help.

For the questions already tagged with it, I can't find the common denominator.

Does anybody else have ideas of how it should be used?

Comment: I tend to get confused, which is my own problem, but could you clarify something please? Of your three example questions, only the first one has the [tag:human-factors] tag. Can you explain why you chose that? Are you saying it doesn't need that tag, or that the others should have some type of "human" tag? Thanks!

Comment: @Sue If we are not going to create human tag, then just ignore after "My only idea"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a great topic. It is definitely not a simple one and hasn't seen much traction on TGO, but is very relevant. The way I understand it, that includes e.g. security topics where you focus on your present state of mind, group dynamics, ... and their influence on your ability to make good decisions. As opposed to objective factors like rock fall, weather, ... My examples are mountaineering focused, but this is applicable more broadly to activities that involve some decision making in the context of judging risks.

So I believe the tag has its use and is much better than just "humans". That is way too broad, as most questions involve humans.

Comment: Could you put an example usage guidance plus questions in your answer? I like the topic you described still not sure human-factors is the best word for it

Comment: Upvote from me. I definitely think we could benefit from something to fit what you're discussing. I don't think "human factors" is it though, and I'm not even sure "human" would be the right word. Perhaps something in the teamwork or interaction category. Let's not give up on this idea!